# Is it right to run crontab service and wsgi within a single docker container

Tags: python, django, docker

Currently, I have a Django wsgi to handle web traffic. (I have a nginx as front end to forward traffic to wsgi)

Now, I would like to start a crobtab service, to run periodic background job.

This is what I had done

---

### django\Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.4-alpine3.4
...

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoint.sh"]

CMD /usr/local/bin/gunicorn web.wsgi:application -b django:5000 --log-level=info --error-logfile=/var/log/gunicorn3.err.log
```

### django\entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

...

python manage.py crontab add

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015624/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container
#
# "crond -help" yields:
#
# -f      Foreground
# -b      Background (default)
# -S      Log to syslog (default)
# -l N    Set log level. Most verbose:0, default:8
# -d N    Set log level, log to stderr
# -L FILE Log to FILE
# -c DIR  Cron dir. Default:/var/spool/cron/crontabs

# start cron
/usr/sbin/crond -f -l 8

exec "$@"
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
  django:
    build:
      context: ./django
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always  
    depends_on:
      - pgbouncer
    expose:
      - "5000"
    volumes:
      - static_data:/app/static
```

---

If I use the above setup, I notice that.

1. My schedule cron worker is running periodically.
2. But, wsgi **unable** to serve web traffic.

First, I try to change in `django\entrypoint.sh`

```
# start cron
/usr/sbin/crond -f -l 8
```

to

```
# start cron
/usr/sbin/crond -b -l 8
```

After making above change,

1. My schedule cron worker is no longer running. Not sure why.
2. wsgi can serve web traffic.

---

May I know why is it so? How can I make my `django` container to serve web traffic, and run cron job at the same time?

Or, is it not the right way to do such thing in Docker? I should use 2 containers?

Answer (score 2):

I'd run a full on second container naming the service in the compose file `cron` or something of the likes (maybe more specific to the actual job in the event you have multiple crons). 1 process per container is general practice. In the "cron" container I wouldn't even run it via `crond` I'd have whatever I'm using on the host machine to handle the scheduling of the container. I'd change your job from being a `django-cron` to a custom `django-admin` command since you won't be managing the running of it with the django app anymore. You could still build the second container off the django one image just change the `CMD` with the `docker-compose.yml` file `command: ["django-admin", "mycommand"]`. Likely would be unnecessary to expose the ports on the second container. Invoke as a normal service `docker-compose run mycronservice`