# How to run cron jobs inside php-fpm-alpine docker container?

Tags: php, docker, cron, alpine-linux, fpm

Hi I don't know how can I run a cron job inside [this](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/c88c3d52f41a370f3a62e3ded62b7b223b4cb846/7.2/alpine3.8/fpm/Dockerfile) container.

I've found this: [How to run a cron job inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015624/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)

But that overrides the CMD, I don't know hot to keep php-fpm working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you need to run multiple processes in your docker container a solution is to use ***supervisord*** as the main instruction. Docker will start and monitor **supervisord** which in turn will start your other processes.

Docker File Example:

```
FROM debian:9
...
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/my.conf"]
```

Supervisord config example (/etc/supervisor/my.conf):

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:cron]
command=/usr/sbin/crond -f -l 8
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
autorestart=true

[program:php-fpm]
command=docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm
```

Note that it is desirable to configure supervisord to output the logs to **/dev/stdout** and **/dev/stderr** to allow docker to handle these logs. Otherwise you risk your container to slow down over time as the amount of file writes increases.

Answer (score 2):

The main question here is how to make PHP work kind of "in parallel" with the cron. And another answer, besides using `supervisor`, is to use **bash's ability** to manage tasks. This is generally mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/).
For the `Alpine PHP-FPM` container and the `Cron`, the startup script would look like this:

Docker File:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine
RUN apk --update add --no-cache bash
COPY ./crontasks /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
COPY entrypoint.bash /usr/sbin
RUN chmod a+x /usr/sbin/entrypoint.bash
ENTRYPOINT /usr/sbin/entrypoint.bash
```

entrypoint.bash file (**the magic is here**)

```
#!/bin/bash
# turn on bash's job control
set -m
# Start the "main" PHP process and put it in the background
php-fpm &
# Start the helper crond process
crond
# now we bring the primary process back into the foreground
fg %1
```

It is important to keep in mind that the cron job syntax in Alpine is different from Debian. And different folders are used for tasks.