# Config Dockerfile for running cronjob

Tags: linux, laravel, docker, nginx, cron

I'm new in Docker and I'm facing a problem with my custom Dockerfile which needs some help from you guys. It's working fine until I add some code to run the cronjob in the docker container.

This is my Dockerfile file:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

COPY cronjobs /etc/crontabs/root

// old commands

ENTRYPOINT ["crond", "-f", "-d", "8"]
```

This is `cronjobs` file:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This is `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx_ctrade
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
      - ./config/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./config/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - ./log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql  
    networks:
      - laravel
    working_dir: /var/www/html

  php:
    build:
      context: ./build
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: php_ctrade
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
      - ./config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql_ctrade
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./config/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
    networks:
      - laravel
```

I re-build the docker images and run it. The cronjob is working ok but when I access the localhost at `localhost:8081`. It isn't working anymore. The page show `502 Bad Gateway`, so I checked the Nginx error log. This is the Nginx error shown me:

```
2020/04/10 13:33:36 [error] 8#8: *28 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.224.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /trades HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://192.168.224.3:9000", host: "localhost:8081", referrer: "http://localhost:8081/home"
```

All the containers are still running after updated.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
a2403ece8509        nginx:stable-alpine   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   18 seconds ago      Up 17 seconds       0.0.0.0:8081->80/tcp   nginx_ctrade
69032097b7e4        ctrade_php            "docker-php-entrypoi…"   19 seconds ago      Up 18 seconds       9000/tcp               php_ctrade
592b483305d5        mysql:latest          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago         Up 18 seconds       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp    mysql_ctrade
```

Is there someone get this issue before? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden yes, they are still running.

Comment: ```RUN echo '* * * * * root php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1' >> /etc/crontab
``` in Dockerfile

Comment: it doesn't work :( @BohdanPetrenko

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, running two (or more) services inside of a Docker container breaks it's philosophy of single responsability.

> It is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by
> using one service per container. That service may fork into multiple
> processes (for example, Apache web server starts multiple worker
> processes). It’s ok to have multiple processes, but to get the most
> benefit out of Docker, avoid one container being responsible for
> multiple aspects of your overall application. [...]

If you choose to follow this recommendation, you will end up with two options:

**Option 1**. Create a separated container that will handle the scheduling tasks.

Example:

```
# File: Dockerfile
FROM php:7.4.8-fpm-alpine
COPY ./cron.d/tasks /cron-tasks
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/log/cron.log
RUN /usr/bin/crontab -u www-data /cron-tasks
CMD ["crond", "-f", "-l", "8"]

# File: cron.d/tasks
* * * * * echo "Cron is working :D" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1

# File: docker-compose.yml
services:
    [...]
    scheduling:
      build:
        context: ./build
        dockerfile: cron.dockerfile
      [...]
```

**Option 2**. Use own host's crontab to execute the scheduled tasks on containers (as defended in [this post](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-setup-cron-and-docker-correctly-a-how-to-guide-9v5f36kz)).

Example:

```
# File on host: /etc/cron.d/my-laravel-apps
*  *  *  *  *  root  docker exec -t laravel-container-A php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
*  *  *  *  *  root  docker exec -t laravel-container-B php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
*  *  *  *  *  root  docker exec -t laravel-container-C php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

PS: In your case, replace <laravel-container-*> by *php_ctrade*.

---

**Option 3:** Use `supervisord`

On the other hand, if you really want just one container at all, you may still use `supervisord` as your main process and configure it to initialize (and supervise) both `php-fpm` and `crontab` applications.

> Note that this is a moderately heavy-weight approach and requires you
> to package supervisord and its configuration in your image (or base
> your image on one that includes supervisord), along with the different
> applications it manages.

You will find an example of how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53960228/4249308).

---

References:

- https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Recommended reading:

- https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container