# dynamic crontab with docker-compose.yaml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cron

I'm trying to build a dynamic cron job using as basis this link: [How to run a cron job inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015624/how-to-run-a-cron-job-inside-a-docker-container)
When I'm  the container $var1 prints the right value, but seens like cron doesnt like env variables....
Any way to go around this?
Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update
RUN apk add rsync run-parts curl
COPY /Scripts/* /
RUN chmod 755 /entry.sh /script.sh /start.sh
#RUN /usr/bin/crontab /crontab.txt
CMD ["/entry.sh"]
```

entry.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# start cron
sh start.sh
/usr/sbin/crond -f -l 8
```

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/crontab /crontab.txt
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    test:
        image: test1
        environment:
            - var1=${var1_env}
```

.env:

```
var1_env=*/1
```

crontab.txt:

```
$var1 * * * * /script.sh >> /var/log/script.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Cronjobs traditionally run in a fresh, clean environment. The behavior you're seeing is that the cron daemon is 'cleaning up' the environment before running your job.

You have two options:

1. Have the cronjob run a shell script. That shell script sets up the environment, then runs the command. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2229861/530160
2. Define the variables inside the crontab. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10657111/530160